# Socket in SIKULI cannot find logging library and fails

Tags: python, sockets, jython, sikuli

I'm trying to run my automation scripts on newest version of SIKULI (v1.1.0). Scripts are writen in python level 2.7 (SIKULI is using Jython).
I'm getting this error:

```html
[error] AttributeError ( !!WHILE IMPORTING!! 'module' object has no attribute 'getLogger' )</br>
[error] --- Traceback --- error source first</br>
line: module ( function ) statement</br>
53: _socket (  <module> ) AttributeError: !!WHILE IMPORTING!! 'module' object has no attribute 'getLogger'</br>
142: xmlrpclib (  <module> )   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sikuli X\sikulix.jar\Lib\socket.py", line 3, in <module></br>
2217: dbf (  <module> )     from xmlrpclib import Marshaller</br>
12: someLib (  <module> )     import dbf</br>
23: Versioning (  <module> )     import someLib</br>
[error] --- Traceback --- end --------------</br>
```

logging is in Lib but it seems like socket can't see it. Aloso I'm using [dbf 0.96.005](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf)

What should cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WHILE IMPORTING 'module' object has no attribute 'getLogger'

Leads me to believe ou are trying to access an attribute on a `module` object.  What you are probably trying to do is access `getLogger` at the class level.

If your import is something like:

```
import someLib
```

and `someLib` is a module that contains the class `someLogger`, you need to write your import like:

```
from someLib import someLogger
```

or else calling `someLib.getLogger()` won't work, as you are accessing from the wrong object.